# ASP.NET Core 2.1 does not recognize Configuration extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to setting up my project but I'm always keep getting this error :

> Cannot convert lambda to type 'ServiceLifetime' because it is not a
>   delegate type.

In my Startup class I did :

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
     Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

And

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddDbContext<ServiceProvider>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings")));
}
```

I even tried to install the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;` but still I'm getting the same error!

Comment: Are you sure your DbContextName is ServiceProvider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is you are using `ServiceProvider` as your `DbContextType` in `services.AddDbContext<TContext>`. Replace the `services.AddDbContext<ServiceProvider>` with `services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>` as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings")));
}
```

Comment: My context class has the "Provider" name as well, I typed the wrong one. It was ProviderContext. 3 AM I'm not in my best time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing ServiceProvider instead of a class of type DbContext. Add a new class derived from DbContext. So here you need to create a class like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
{
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options):base(options){
}
}
```

and in startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings")));
}
```